# Окончание существительного 1 склонения

Tags: склонение

Выписал отрывок из предложения, которое было дано в учебнике,

> ..., пронесся несколько сажен, и опускается с добычею в траву или жниву...

Мне кажется, что в этом предложении есть ошибка и она заключается в следующем: добыча - 1 склонение, с добычею - творительный падеж, а в творительном падеже должно быть окончание либо -ой, либо -ей, тогда в учебнике ошибка, должно быть с добычей? Или тут какое-то другое правило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки нет. Во времена Аксакова в творительном падеже существительных 1 склонения наряду с -ей нередко употреблялось окончание -ею.

В I склонении вариантные окончания наблюдаются в творительном падеже. Наряду с основным, стилистически нейтральным окончанием -ой (-ей) встречается -ою (-ею), свойственное книжной поэтической речи. Например: Однажды, темною порою, по камням берегом крутым наш витязь ехал над рекою. (П.)(http://studysphere.ru/work.php?id=257)

Comment: А вот, если я напишу, например, в сочинении, с добычею, будет ли это считаться ошибкоЙ?

Comment: Не будет. Такое окончаие и сейчас употребляется. В любом случае, если вы цитируете, то можно указать в скобках, что орфография (и/или пунктуация) автора.

Answer (score 1):

По сути вам ответили. Только добавлю, что, если речь идет о цитате, то в учебнике не может быть ошибки в принципе. Цитируется всегда так, как у автора (с поправкой только на орфографические изменения - да и то не всегда). Таким образом, либо это ошибка автора (что в данном случае невозможно), либо неточноть при цитировании, которой в данном случае тоже нет. Но это уже другой разговор.